# What is meant by "a plane wave that has the periodicity of a Bravais lattice"?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, plane-wave

I'm reading through Ashcroft & Mermin's chapter on reciprocal lattices and am confused about this sentence:

> Consider a set of points **R** constituting a Bravais lattice, and a
> plane wave, e^{i **k*r**}. For general **k**, such a plane wave will
> not, of course, have the periodicity of the Bravais lattice,

I understand what a Bravais lattice is in that it's infinitely repeating and looks the same no matter which unit's perspective you take. I'm just puzzled by what this part means.

Comment: A lattice has a specific periodicity (it is a Bravais lattice after all). Some random plane wave is unlikely to have that periodicity, so the random wave would look different depending on which unit cell you happened to be sitting at.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it simply means $e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r} + \vec{R})} = e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}$, for any Bravais lattice vector $\vec{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

A wave as:$\psi = Ae^{i \mathbf{k.r}} = A$ always where: $\mathbf{k.r} = 2n\pi$. Or $k_1x + k_2y + k_3z = 2n\pi$. It is the equation of a family of parallel planes, all of them normal to $\mathbf k$.

The distance between that planes is not related to the lattice interpanar distance.